# function constrained optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization

Good afternoon,

I have a problem with constrained optimization in R: i have a polynomial function in several variables to optimize:

```
fq = function(w) {
S = 1
for (t in 1:tempo) {
    St = 0
    for (i in 1:ntitoli) {
        St = St + w[i]*df[t,i]
        }
    S = S*St
    }
-S
}
```

whit linear constrains;
using the function constrOptim the result change if I change the starting point, so i think that this function finds a local minimum in the neighbor of my starting point. Is there an optimization function that finds a GLOBAL minimum(maximum) in my constrained set? I have already search but i have find nothing

Thanks for attention

Comment: You might have luck with the **DEoptim** package, which uses differential evolution to optimize the objective function. Genetic algorithms are known for being good at finding global optima. There is also a C++ version of the `DEoptim` function in **RcppDE**.

Comment: Listen to my mate up here, but never be too optimistic about finding global optima in non-convex optimization. These problems are terribly complex. HOWEVER, if your polynomial is univariate, be sure to plot it! Just do it and you might at least learn in which neighborhood the global minimum lies. If it's multivariate, then just stick to GAs and hope for the best...