# constrained optimization R: another example

Tags: r, optimization

I am attempting to perform constrained optimization in R.  I have looked at these posts and a couple of others:

[constrained optimization in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436630/constrained-optimization-in-r)

[function constrained optimization in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044421/function-constrained-optimization-in-r)

The first post above is quite helpful, but I am still not obtaining the correct answer to my problem.

My function is:

```
Fd <- 224 * d1 + 84 * d2 + d1 * d2 - 2 * d1^2 - d2^2
```

and my constraint is: `3 * d1 + d2 = 280`

First I find the correct answer using an unconstrained exhaustive search followed by a constrained exhaustive search:

```
my.data <- expand.grid(x1 = seq(0, 200, 1), x2 = seq(0, 200, 1))
head(my.data)
dim(my.data)

d1     <- my.data[,1]
d2     <- my.data[,2]

Fd <- 224 * d1 + 84 * d2 + d1 * d2 - 2 * d1^2 - d2^2

new.data <- data.frame(Fd = Fd, d1 = d1, d2 = d2)
head(new.data)

# identify values of d1 and d2 that maximize Fd without the constraint
new.data[new.data$Fd == max(new.data$Fd),]
# **This is the correct answer**
#         Fd d1 d2
# 6157 11872 76 80


# Impose constraint
new.data <- new.data[(3 * new.data$d1 + new.data$d2) == 280, ]

# identify values of d1 and d2 that maximize Fd with the constraint
new.data[new.data$Fd == max(new.data$Fd),]
# **This is the correct answer**
#          Fd d1 d2
# 14743 11774 69 73
```

Now find unconstrained maxima using `optim`.  This works.

```
    Fd <- function(betas) {

         b1 = betas[1]
         b2 = betas[2]

         (224 * b1 + 84 * b2 + b1 * b2 - 2 * b1^2 - b2^2)

    }

    # unconstrained
    optim(c(60, 100), Fd, control=list(fnscale=-1), method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
    # $par
    # [1] 75.99999 79.99995
```

Now find constrained maxima using `constrOptim`.  This does not work.

```
b1.lower.bound <- c(0, 280)
b1.upper.bound <- c(93.33333, 0)
b2.lower.bound <- c(93.33333, 0)
b2.upper.bound <- c(0, 280)

theta = c(60,100)                         # starting values
ui = rbind(c(280,0), c(0,93.33333))       # range of allowable values
theta %*% ui                              # obtain ci as -1 * theta %*% ui
#       [,1]     [,2]
# [1,] 16800 9333.333

constrOptim(c(60,100), Fd, NULL, ui = rbind(c(280,0), c(0,93.33333)), ci = c(-16800, -9333.333), control=list(fnscale=-1))
# $par
# [1] 75.99951 80.00798
```

I have tried playing around with `ui` and `ci`, but it seems like no matter what values I use for them I always get the same answer as with unconstrained `optim`.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Note that in this case you could solve the constraint for d1 (or d2) and substitute that into the objective function reducing the problem to an unconstrained problem in one variable.

Comment: Thank you.  That is a neat idea.  Although, for completeness I still hope to learn how to solve it using constrained optimization as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constrOptim()` uses linear **inequality** constraints and defines the feasible region by `ui %*% param - ci >= 0`. If the constraint is `3 * d1 + d2 <= 280`,  `ui` is `c(-3, -1)` and `ci` is `-280`.

constrOptim(); **inequality** constraint is: **3 * d1 + d2 <= 280**

```
Fd <- function(betas) {
    b1 = betas[1]
    b2 = betas[2]
   (224 * b1 + 84 * b2 + b1 * b2 - 2 * b1^2 - b2^2)
}

theta = c(59.999,100)    # because of needing " ui %*% inital_par - ci > 0 "
ui = c(-3, -1)
ci = -280                # those ui & ci mean " -3*par[1] + -1*par[2] + 280 >= 0 "

constrOptim(theta, Fd, NULL, ui = ui, ci = ci, control=list(fnscale=-1))
  # $par
  # [1] 69.00002 72.99993
```

[Edited]

If you want not inequality but equality constraints, it would be better to use `Rsolnp` or `alabama` package. They can use **inequality and/or equality** constraints (see [Constrained Optimization library for equality and inequality constraints](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19792/constrained-optimization-library-for-equality-and-inequality-constraints)).

solnp(); auglag(); **equality** constraint is: **3 * d1 + d2 = 280**

```
library(Rsolnp); library(alabama); 

Fd2 <- function(betas) {     #  -1 * Fd
   b1 = betas[1]
   b2 = betas[2]
   -1 * (224 * b1 + 84 * b2 + b1 * b2 - 2 * b1^2 - b2^2)
}

eqFd <- function(betas) {  # the equality constraint
    b1 = betas[1]
    b2 = betas[2]
    (3 * b1 + b2 -280)
}

solnp(pars = c(60, 100), fun = Fd2, eqfun = eqFd, eqB = 0)
auglag(par = c(60, 100), fn = Fd2, heq = eqFd)
```

Comment: Is the (-3, -1) the negatives of the slopes on the constraint: 3 * b1 + b2 = 280?

Comment: `constrOptim()` uses linear inequality constraints. In this case, I constrained `3 * b1 + b2 <= 280` and it is equivalent to `-3 * b1 - b2 + 280 >= 0` (does this answer your question?)

Comment: I think so.  Thank you very much.  This is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.  I will likely accept your answer tomorrow.  I like to wait at least 24-hours.  I am curious why those other two R packages are better.  Although, I realize we are not supposed to have long discussions in comments.

Comment: @MarkMiller; No worries. I introduced [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19792/constrained-optimization-library-for-equality-and-inequality-constraints) to your comment.

Comment: I am accepting your answer.  It was _very_ helpful.  However, I think you might have misspelled the name of the `Rsolnp` package.

Comment: This is a really nice answer.  I wish I could upvote it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have implemented G. Grothendieck's suggestion and it seems to return the correct answer.  Although, ideally I would like to learn how to obtain the correct answer using constrained optimization.  I used the Brent method here because there is only one variable.  Note that I had to provide upper and lower limits in the `optim` statement.

```
# Find maxima using optim and substitution.  First remove b2
#
# 3 * b1 + b2 = 280
#
# b2 = (280 - 3 * b1)

Fd <- function(betas) {

     b1 = betas[1]

     (224 * b1 + 84 * (280 - 3 * b1) + b1 * (280 - 3 * b1) - 2 * b1^2 - (280 - 3 * b1)^2)

}

optim(c(60), Fd, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 93.33333, control=list(fnscale=-1))
# $par
# [1] 69

# Now remove b1
#
# 3 * b1 + b2 = 280
#
# b1 = ((280 - b2) / 3)

Fd <- function(betas) {

     b2 = betas[1]

     (224 * ((280 - b2) / 3) + 84 * b2 + ((280 - b2) / 3) * b2 - 2 * ((280 - b2) / 3)^2 - b2^2)

}

optim(c(100), Fd, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 280, control=list(fnscale=-1))
# $par
# [1] 73
```

Comment: Also note that this is a quadratic so it couild be solved analytically.